# why does my jquery only affect the first entry of my iron-list?

Tags: jquery, html, css, polymer

I have an iron-list on which I am wanting to, when clicking an entry of the list, a left hand border appear and disappear when clicking off/another entry.

I have managed to scour the pages to find a bit of JQuery that looked promising and enables me to get the border on the first entry, however it stops here. When clicking other entries, the top entry gains the border and not the entry clicked.

Any help?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <dom-module id="test-app-test">
    <template>
      <style>
        div {
          height: 20px;
          border-bottom: 1px lightgrey solid;
        }
        .red {
          border-left: 10px solid red;
        }
      </style>
        <div class="hello" on-click="toggleClass">hello</div>
        <div class="hello" on-click="toggleClass">hello</div>
        <div class="hello" on-click="toggleClass">hello</div>
        <div class="hello" on-click="toggleClass">hello</div> 
        <div class="hello" on-click="toggleClass">hello</div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
          is: 'test-app-test',
          properties: {
            bgc: {
              type: String,
              observer: 'bgcChanged'
            }
          },
          toggleClass: function(e) {
            var toggleBorder = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('.hello');
            $(toggleBorder).toggleClass('red');
          },
         bgcChanged: function() {
            var toggleBorder = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('.hello');
            toggleBorder.style.backgroundColor = this.bgc;
          }
        });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with Polymer, but by following the code it appears to me that the use of `.querySelector('.hello')` might only find the first appearance of the class. Here is how you could do it without using Polymer within the `toggleClass` function.

```
toggleClass: function(e) {
  $(e.target).parent().find('.red').removeClass('red');
  $(e.target).addClass('red');
},
```

*Note: I cannot test this to make sure it works in your example.*

Comment: Hey Gwellin, thanks for the effort. I can see where you're coming from but I couldn't get it to work after tweaking a few things. I'm not so hot on JS/JQuery in Polymer myself.

Comment: I'm surprised that didn't work, unless that means `this` is a reference to something other than the clicked element. Perhaps swapping `this` with `e.target` in my example code would work. (`e` is the *event* reference, and `.target` is the element which triggered the event)

Comment: @Gwellin word `this` is reserved to whole element in Polymer. So that's why your example won't work in Polymer

Comment: e.target WORKS! Owe you one big time Gwellin! Now I just have to try and get it working on my actual code rather than just a test :-P

Answer (score 0):

Using `querySelector` selects only first occurence. just replace `querySelector` by `querySelectorAll` and it will work

BTW. for using `toggleClass` you don't need jquery. Polymer has built-in methods too. https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-toggleClass

Comment: Hey Kuba, any chance that you could give me an example of how you would solve my problem using the toggleClass function?